std::vector не может быть constexpr?
В каких случаях/каким способом я могу создать константный вектор времени компиляции?
Вот например. С++ ругается на строку
constexpr auto vvv0 = std::vector<int>(4, 0);

gcc:

the type 'const std::vector' of 'constexpr' variable 'vvv0' is not literal

clang:

constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const std::vector'

Visual Studio:

выражение должно иметь константное значение
недопустимое использование адреса хранилища интерпретатора

Хотя тут явно вектор порожден от литералов. И в стандарте написано, что

22.3.11.2 Constructors, copy, and assignment
constexpr vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());

Preconditions: T is Cpp17CopyInsertable into *this.

Effects: Constructs a vector with n copies of value, using the specified allocator.
Цитата

Complexity: Linear in n.
...



Интересно, что в исходниках QT конструкторы вектора не constexpr))))
А вот в Visual Studio вполне себе
    constexpr vector(const size_type _Count, const _Ty& _Val, const _Alloc& _Al = _Alloc())
        : _Mypair(_One_then_variadic_args_t{}, _Al) {
        _Construct_n(_Count, _Val);
    }

В каких случаях/каким способом я могу создать константный вектор времени компиляции?
(вопрос, естественно, относится не только к векторам и не только к конструктору, выбранному в качестве примера)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801072/2452869

@AntonMenshov но error: the type 'const std::vector' of 'constexpr' variable 'vvv0' is not literalx86-64 gcc 13.2 #1

@AntonMenshov, я правда, не понимаю. В Вашей ссылке, вроде, написано, что уже добавлено в gcc 12. Но всё-равно ошибка.

Компилируете с каким стандартом? C++11\14\17\20\23? И далее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498591/2452869

@AntonMenshov в QT set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) в VS Стандарт ISO C++ 20 (/std:c++20)

@AntonMenshov ааааааа, всё. Дошло кажись "вы можете использовать только временное выделение."
constexpr auto QQQ() { return std::vector<int>{ 4,2,3,5,4,3 }.size(); } ... constexpr auto vvv1 = QQQ(); Так работает. Спасибо

Именно так. Советую посмотреть в сторону std::array.

В исходниках Qt свой QVector, а не имплементация std::vector.

@αλεχολυτ при создании нового проекта в Qt можно выбрать "Проект без Qt"

Ради интереса поставил Qt 6.7 Kit под MSVC2019 и там contsexpr конструктор: _CONSTEXPR20 vector() noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<_Alty>) ...

хм... Qt Creator 11.0.3 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) И тут /**        *  @brief  Creates a %vector with no elements.        *  @param  __a  An allocator object.        */       explicit       vector(const allocator_type& __a) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT       : _Base(__a) { }

а что там в шапке хидера ? У тебя похоже хидер не от MS судя по _GLIBCXX..

@αλεχολυτ ой, а можете немного пояснить? Там много текста под комментариями, потом includ'ы. Один из них #include <bits/stl_vector.h>. А уже в нём тот самый vector с тем самым конструктором. И именно туда он прыгает при компиляции в отладочном режиме.

У Qt есть разные подготовленные наборы (Kits). Если ставить на винду, то можно выбрать, например, MSVC, MinGW, clang. В зависимости от того какой набор выбран для проекта, будет тот или иной хидер. Выше я привёл пример для <vector> при использовании MSVC набора. Для MinGW будет gcc'шный. Вот, например, текущая версия конструктора vector с итераторами. Но у Qt может быть более древняя, конечно.

ну чтож, как говорится, принял к сведению, @αλεχολυτ . <3

Если вектор создали во время компиляции, он должен и умереть во время компиляции. Например, он может быть локальной переменной в constexpr функции, но сам не обязательно константный.
В общем случае, память выделенная через new во время компиляции, должна быть освобождена через delete тоже во время компиляции. Видимо потому, что иначе непонятно, как перенести ее в кучу при запуске приложения.

Интересно, а какой тогда смысл в спецификации constexpr для методов, если они и без неё могут участвовать в создании констант времени компиляции?

@HalturinEvgeniy Почему, не могут. Пример бы.

точно, что-то я вчера напутал с этим. Вот. Не робит, как ему и положено.
